# Finding an Excel spreadsheet to plan GPO deployment

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, microsoft-excel

My boss gave me a spreadsheet that he says he found from MSFT somewhere.  The problem is the spreadsheet is for 2003 GPOs and I need to find one for 2008.  The spreadsheet lists all of the available Group Policy Editors Nodes, as well as the policy setting.  I've searched and am unable to find a link for this spreadsheet (either 2003 or 2008).  Does anyone know where I can find it?
Note:  It's not the spreadsheet located [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=18c90c80-8b0a-4906-a4f5-ff24cc2030fb&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748655.aspx

the last time I looked it still had the spreadsheet with all the possible gpos settings!

Comment: While it's not a spreadsheet, the Security Compliance Manager might be what I'm looking for.  I'll have to play around with it to be sure.  Thanks.

Comment: look in the directories that were extracted, it use to be in there. Does the newest executable create gpo's that you can then link to? I have the most currentl verision of the xls gpo settings but its at home. I'll post a link tonight.

Comment: ok I have a copy of the previous one that ms did its for w2k8+, but I can't use any of the upload sites from work.. I can email it to you if you'd like.

Comment: aahhg the spreadsheet has activex content and it got quarnatined on the way out..  still working on it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe Microsoft is maintaining the excel spreadsheet any more.  A support tech at Microsoft has created a new tool for searching through various policies and researching them.  The new policy reference tool is available here http://gps.cloudapp.net/.

The blog entry announcing this new service is [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/06/24/announcing-the-group-policy-search-service.aspx).

Comment: Blast.  I hope that's not the case.  Ideally I need something that I can customize.  Thanks for the pointer though.  It's still helpful.